# Querying a 'column' in core data

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a core data entity named "Folder". Each "Folder" has a 1-to-many relationship with the entity "File", and each file contains the field "filename".

What is a succinct way of producing an array of all of the filenames for a given folder? 
I expected it to be something like:

```
NSManagedObject* folder = [self getSomeFolder];
NSArray* files = [folder valueForKey:@"files.@unionOfSet.filename"];
```

... but i've been having no luck getting it to go, and Apple's set operations guide has got me stumped.

Comment: I think this could work but am not at a the mac to check:
    NSArray* files = [folder valueForKey:@"files"];
    NSArray* fileNames = [files valueForKey:@"filename"];

If this is the case I will be horribly embarrassed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is mostly correct, but you need to use `-valueForKeyPath:` instead of `-valueForKey:`. `-valueForKey:` is optimized for keys that do not contain multiple elements (separated by `.`).

Comment: Cheers mate, probably saved me a lot of frustration!

Comment: No worries. This one bites me at least once a project.

Comment: Clarifying: A key path is one or more keys, separated by ‘.’. A single key cannot contain a ‘.’, because that would form a key path of two keys. Either method will work with a single key, but for a key path, you must use `valueForKeyPath:`.